# Data is not saving to txt document but txt document gets created

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import re
import time
uk=open("uknp.txt", "w")
nnstd=open("nnstdnp.txt", "w")
uk.close()
nnstd.close()

while 1:
    distance=1
    print("------------------------------------")
    registration = input("Please Enter the Registration Plate: ").lower()
    time = float(input("How long did it take you to reach 1 mile in seconds: "))
    speed=((distance/time)*60)*60
    print("Car",registration,"was going at" ,"%.2f" %speed,"Mph")
    if speed>60:
        if re.match("[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}!", registration):
            uk=open("uknp.txt", "a")
            uk.write(registration + speed)
            uk.close()
        else:
            nnstd.open("nnstd.txt", "a")
            nnstd.write(registration+speed)
            nnstd.close()
```

It is meant to upload to a text document the registration plate and the speed and if it is valid or not.

Comment: You have `nnstd.open("nnstd.txt", "a")` instead of nnstd = open. Are both files failing to write the info you need?

Comment: yes both are failing

Comment: What exactly is your output? Does it still print "Car ### was going at #Mph"? Also you're trying to write `string + int` with `registration + speed`

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in you code.

- you create initialy a `nnstdnp.txt` file and later write a `nnstd.txt`
- you have `nnstd.open("nnstd.txt", "a")` when it should be `nnstd=open("nnstd.txt", "a")`
- you try to concatenate string and float (=> raises `TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly`) in `xx.write(registration + speed)` when it should be `xx.write(registration + ("%02f" % speed))`
- you have no end condition to go out of your `while 1:` loop ; it could be :

  ```
  registration = input("Please Enter the Registration Plate: ").lower()
  if len(registration) == 0: break
  ```

As a general advice, when thing goes wrong, you should try to add `print` calls to see what happens exactly and what branches of `if` are followed.